# UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash **** does not match

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm receiving this error from facebook **only** in a few devices. 
I've searched through a bunch of other questions here regarding the same issue but I did not find any with working devices and not working ones.
Login proved to work in:
Motorola Defy.
Samsung galaxy S3.
Login gives Key Hash not match on:
Samsung galaxy S2.
Samsung galaxy Nexus.

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.5.2.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved it.

Run this:

> keytool -alias **ALIAS** -exportcert -keystore **FULL KEY NAME** |
>   openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

In **ALIAS** without quotes put the alias you used to generate the key. If you are exporting your apk via eclipse, you can find the alias in export wizard.

In **FULL KEY NAME** without quotes put your release key including extension(.keystore).

Keytool **will** ask for the password!
If keytool doesn't ask for password, then you're doing it wrong.